# aws cfn-init failing for AccessDenied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-auto-scaling

I have to run cfn-init for an autoscaling group but it is failing:

```
/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ms-lbas-split1-EC2LauncConfigStack-1GB6170KAE3EU --resource LaunchConfig --region us-west-2
AccessDenied: Instance i-02c0239a16cd96a53 is not allowed to call DescribeStackResource for ms-lbas-split1-EC2LauncConfigStack-1GB6170KAE3EU
```

The policy is on * and, indeed, i can call describe-stack-resource on the same entity and it is working fine:

```
[root@ip-172-31-18-99 ec2-user]# aws cloudformation describe-stack-resource     --stack-name ms-lbas-split1-EC2LauncConfigStack-1GB6170KAE3EU   --logical-resource-id LaunchConfig  --region us-west-2
{
    "StackResourceDetail": {
        "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:020779576776:stack/ms-lbas-split1-EC2LauncConfigStack-1GB6170KAE3EU/cdf015d0-9d88-11ed-8084-0af2362739b7",
        "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
        "DriftInformation": {
            "StackResourceDriftStatus": "NOT_CHECKED"
        },
        "ResourceType": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
        "LastUpdatedTimestamp": "2023-01-26T14:53:46.144Z",
        "StackName": "ms-lbas-split1-EC2LauncConfigStack-1GB6170KAE3EU",
        "PhysicalResourceId": "ms-lbas-split1-EC2LauncConfigStack-1GB6170KAE3EU-LaunchConfig-IqXSDhGUFDY1",
        "Metadata": "{\"Comment\":\"Install a simple application\",\"AWS::CloudFormation::Init\":{\"config\":{\"files\":{\"/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf\":{\"mode\":\"000400\",\"owner\":\"root\",\"content\":\"[main]\\nstack=arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:020779576776:stack/ms-lbas-split1/86b538d0-9d88-11ed-8250-0a502f832635\\nregion=us-west-2\\n\",\"group\":\"root\"},\"/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf\":{\"mode\":\"000400\",\"owner\":\"root\",\"content\":\"[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]\\ntriggers=post.update\\npath=Resources.LaunchConfig.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init\\naction=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v          --stack ms-lbas-split1-EC2LauncConfigStack-1GB6170KAE3EU         --resource LaunchConfig          --region us-west-2\\nrunas=root\\n\",\"group\":\"root\"},\"/var/www/html/index.html\":{\"mode\":\"000644\",\"owner\":\"root\",\"content\":\"<img src=\\\"\\nhttps://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-us-west-2\\n/cloudformation_graphic.png\\\" alt=\\\"AWS CloudFormation Logo\\\"/>\\n<h1>Congratulations, you have successfully launched the AWS CloudFormation sample.</h1>\",\"group\":\"root\"}},\"services\":{\"sysvinit\":{\"cfn-hup\":{\"files\":[\"/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf\",\"/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf\"],\"ensureRunning\":\"true\",\"enabled\":\"true\"},\"httpd\":{\"ensureRunning\":\"true\",\"enabled\":\"true\"}}},\"packages\":{\"yum\":{\"httpd\":[]}}}}}",
        "LogicalResourceId": "LaunchConfig"
    }
```

I have this problem only when I am using those nested cloudformation template:

Main one:

```
 "Resources": {
        "WebServerGroup" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
            "Properties" : {
              "VPCZoneIdentifier" : { "Ref" : "AWSsubnetid" }, 
              "LaunchConfigurationName" : { 
                "Fn::GetAtt": ["EC2LauncConfigStack", "Outputs.LaunchConfig"]                    
                },
              "MinSize" : "2",
              "MaxSize" : "2",
              "TargetGroupARNs" : [ { "Ref" : "ALBTargetGroup" } ]
            },                
            "CreationPolicy" : {                  
              "ResourceSignal" : {
                "Timeout" : "PT60M"
              }

            },
            "UpdatePolicy": {
              "AutoScalingRollingUpdate": {
                "MinInstancesInService": "1",
                "MaxBatchSize": "1",
                "PauseTime" : "PT15M",
                "WaitOnResourceSignals": "true"
              }
            }
          },
      
          "EC2LauncConfigStack": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Properties": {
                "TemplateURL": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "https://ms-tst-launcongi-12343.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ec2_EC2LauncConfigStack-v2.json"
                },                
                "Parameters":{
                  "StackName": {
                    "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" 
                  },
                  "StackId": {
                    "Ref" : "AWS::StackId" 
                  },
                  "InstanceSecGroup" : {
                    "Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroup"
                  }
              }     
              }                                  
            },
      
          "ApplicationLoadBalancer" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
            "DependsOn":"InstanceSecurityGroupHttp",
            "Properties" : {
              "Subnets" : { "Ref" : "AWSsubnetid"},
              "SecurityGroups" : [ { "Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroupHttp" } ]
            }
          },
      
          "ALBListener" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
            "Properties" : {
              "DefaultActions" : [{
                "Type" : "forward",
                "TargetGroupArn" : { "Ref" : "ALBTargetGroup" }
              }],
              "LoadBalancerArn" : { "Ref" : "ApplicationLoadBalancer" },
              "Port" : "80",
              "Protocol" : "HTTP"
            }
          },
      
          "ALBTargetGroup" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
            "Properties" : {
              "HealthCheckIntervalSeconds" : 30,
              "HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds" : 5,
              "HealthyThresholdCount" : 3,
              "Port" : 80,
              "Protocol" : "HTTP",
              "UnhealthyThresholdCount" : 5,
              "VpcId" : {"Ref" : "AWSvpcid"}
            }
          },
      
          "InstanceSecurityGroup" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties" : {
              "GroupDescription" : "Enable SSH access and HTTP access on the inbound port",
              "SecurityGroupIngress" : [ {
                "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                "FromPort" : "80",
                "ToPort" : "80",
                "SourceSecurityGroupId" : {"Fn::Select" : [0, {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["ApplicationLoadBalancer", "SecurityGroups"]}]}
              },{
                "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                "FromPort" : "22",
                "ToPort" : "22",
                "CidrIp" : { "Ref" : "RemoteAccessCIDR"}
              } ],
              "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "AWSvpcid" }
            }
          },
          "InstanceSecurityGroupHttp" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties" : {
              "GroupDescription" : "Enable HTTP access on the inbound port",
              "SecurityGroupIngress" : [ {
                "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                "FromPort" : "80",
                "ToPort" : "80",
                "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
              } ],
              "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "AWSvpcid" }
            }
          }
          
        },
```

Nested:

```
    [...]


"PolicyDocument": {
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": [
                                "*"

                            ],
                            "Resource": "*"
                        },   
[...]
    "LaunchConfig" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
            "Metadata" : {
              "Comment" : "Install a simple application",
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
                "config" : {
                  "packages" : {
                    "yum" : {
                      "httpd"             : []
                    }
                  },
      
                  "files" : {
                    "/var/www/html/index.html" : {
                      "content" : { "Fn::Join" : ["\n", [
                        "<img src=\"", {"Fn::FindInMap" : ["Region2Examples", {"Ref" : "AWS::Region"}, "Examples"]}, "/cloudformation_graphic.png\" alt=\"AWS CloudFormation Logo\"/>",
                        "<h1>Congratulations, you have successfully launched the AWS CloudFormation sample.</h1>"
                      ]]},
                      "mode"    : "000644",
                      "owner"   : "root",
                      "group"   : "root"
                    },
      
                    "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf" : {
                      "content" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                        "[main]\n",
                        "stack=", { "Ref" : "StackId" }, "\n",
                        "region=", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n"
                      ]]},
                      "mode"    : "000400",
                      "owner"   : "root",
                      "group"   : "root"
                    },
      
                    "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf" : {
                      "content": { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                        "[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]\n",
                        "triggers=post.update\n",
                        "path=Resources.LaunchConfig.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init\n",
                        "action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                        "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "StackName" },
                        "         --resource LaunchConfig ",
                        "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",
                        "runas=root\n"
                      ]]},
                      "mode"    : "000400",
                      "owner"   : "root",
                      "group"   : "root"
                    }
                  },
      
                  "services" : {
                    "sysvinit" : {
                      "httpd"    : { "enabled" : "true", "ensureRunning" : "true" },
                      "cfn-hup" : { "enabled" : "true", "ensureRunning" : "true",
                                    "files" : ["/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf", "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf"]}
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "Properties" : {
              "ImageId" :{ "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSRegionArch2AMI", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },
                { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSInstanceType2Arch", { "Ref" : "AWSInstanceType" }, "Arch" ] } ] },
              "SecurityGroups" : [ { "Ref" : "InstanceSecGroup" } ],
              "IamInstanceProfile": { "Ref": "HostProfile" },
              "InstanceType" : { "Ref" : "AWSInstanceType" },
              "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "AWSKeyPairName" },
              "UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                   "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
                   "yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",
      
                   "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                   "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
                   "         --resource LaunchConfig ",
                   "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",
      
                   "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
                   "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "StackName" },
                   "         --resource WebServerGroup ",
                   "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n"
              ]]}}
            }
          }              
    },
```

I have chopped out few things. Exactly the same code is running fine when I am using one single stack:

```
{

    "Resources": {
        "WebServerGroup" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
            "Properties" : {
              "VPCZoneIdentifier" : { "Ref" : "AWSsubnetid" }, 
              "LaunchConfigurationName" : { "Ref" : "LaunchConfig" },
              "MinSize" : "2",
              "MaxSize" : "2",
              "TargetGroupARNs" : [ { "Ref" : "ALBTargetGroup" } ]
            },
            "CreationPolicy" : {
              "ResourceSignal" : {
                "Timeout" : "PT15M"
              }
            },
            "UpdatePolicy": {
              "AutoScalingRollingUpdate": {
                "MinInstancesInService": "1",
                "MaxBatchSize": "1",
                "PauseTime" : "PT15M",
                "WaitOnResourceSignals": "true"
              }
            }
          },
      
          "LaunchConfig" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
            "Metadata" : {
              "Comment" : "Install a simple application",
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
                "config" : {
                  "packages" : {
                    "yum" : {
                      "httpd"             : []
                    }
                  },
      
                  "files" : {
                    "/var/www/html/index.html" : {
                      "content" : { "Fn::Join" : ["\n", [
                        "<img src=\"", {"Fn::FindInMap" : ["Region2Examples", {"Ref" : "AWS::Region"}, "Examples"]}, "/cloudformation_graphic.png\" alt=\"AWS CloudFormation Logo\"/>",
                        "<h1>Congratulations, you have successfully launched the AWS CloudFormation sample.</h1>"
                      ]]},
                      "mode"    : "000644",
                      "owner"   : "root",
                      "group"   : "root"
                    },
      
                    "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf" : {
                      "content" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                        "[main]\n",
                        "stack=", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackId" }, "\n",
                        "region=", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n"
                      ]]},
                      "mode"    : "000400",
                      "owner"   : "root",
                      "group"   : "root"
                    },
      
                    "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf" : {
                      "content": { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                        "[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]\n",
                        "triggers=post.update\n",
                        "path=Resources.LaunchConfig.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init\n",
                        "action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                        "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
                        "         --resource LaunchConfig ",
                        "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",
                        "runas=root\n"
                      ]]},
                      "mode"    : "000400",
                      "owner"   : "root",
                      "group"   : "root"
                    }
                  },
      
                  "services" : {
                    "sysvinit" : {
                      "httpd"    : { "enabled" : "true", "ensureRunning" : "true" },
                      "cfn-hup" : { "enabled" : "true", "ensureRunning" : "true",
                                    "files" : ["/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf", "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf"]}
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "Properties" : {
              "ImageId" :{ "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSRegionArch2AMI", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },
                { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSInstanceType2Arch", { "Ref" : "AWSInstanceType" }, "Arch" ] } ] },
              "SecurityGroups" : [ { "Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroup" } ],
              "InstanceType" : { "Ref" : "AWSInstanceType" },
              "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "AWSKeyPairName" },
              "UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                   "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
                   "yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",
      
                   "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                   "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
                   "         --resource LaunchConfig ",
                   "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",
      
                   "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
                   "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
                   "         --resource WebServerGroup ",
                   "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n"
              ]]}}
            }
          },
      
          "ApplicationLoadBalancer" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
          
            "Properties" : {
              "Subnets" : { "Ref" : "AWSsubnetid"},
              "SecurityGroups" : [ { "Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroupHttp" } ]
            }
          },
      
          "ALBListener" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
            "Properties" : {
              "DefaultActions" : [{
                "Type" : "forward",
                "TargetGroupArn" : { "Ref" : "ALBTargetGroup" }
              }],
              "LoadBalancerArn" : { "Ref" : "ApplicationLoadBalancer" },
              "Port" : "80",
              "Protocol" : "HTTP"
            }
          },
      
          "ALBTargetGroup" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
            "Properties" : {
              "HealthCheckIntervalSeconds" : 30,
              "HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds" : 5,
              "HealthyThresholdCount" : 3,
              "Port" : 80,
              "Protocol" : "HTTP",
              "UnhealthyThresholdCount" : 5,
              "VpcId" : {"Ref" : "AWSvpcid"}
            }
          },
      
          "InstanceSecurityGroup" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties" : {
              "GroupDescription" : "Enable SSH access and HTTP access on the inbound port",
              "SecurityGroupIngress" : [ {
                "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                "FromPort" : "80",
                "ToPort" : "80",
                "SourceSecurityGroupId" : {"Fn::Select" : [0, {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["ApplicationLoadBalancer", "SecurityGroups"]}]}
              },{
                "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                "FromPort" : "22",
                "ToPort" : "22",
                "CidrIp" : { "Ref" : "RemoteAccessCIDR"}
              } ],
              "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "AWSvpcid" }
            }
          },
          "InstanceSecurityGroupHttp" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties" : {
              "GroupDescription" : "Enable HTTP access on the inbound port",
              "SecurityGroupIngress" : [ {
                "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                "FromPort" : "80",
                "ToPort" : "80",
                "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
              } ],
              "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "AWSvpcid" }
            }
          }
        
        },
      
        "Outputs" : {
          "URL" : {
            "Description" : "URL of the website",
            "Value" :  { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [ "http://", { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "ApplicationLoadBalancer", "DNSName" ]}]]}
          }
        }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I'm not sure *why* this is happening, but to resolve this you need to pass the --role parameter through to cfn-init.

I also expected it to use the IAM Role assigned to the instance(s), but that doesn't seem to be the case:

In the `UserData` section of the LaunchConfiguration (same applies to LaunchTemplates as well)

```
                   "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                   "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
                   "         --resource LaunchConfig ",
                   "         --role YourRoleNameHere",
                   "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",
```

The role needs to be the name of the IAM Role you assigned to the instance.

Same applies to the cfn-signal part of the `UserData` section. And the `cfn-hup.conf` and `cfn-auto-reloader.conf` config files you create in your Init script.